# How to Design/Configure PCLs(Portable Class Libraries) with Dependencies?

Tags: c#, json.net, dependencies, dependency-management, portable-class-library

I have a Portable Class Library (Targets .Net462 and .Net Core).

It has a dependency on Newtonsoft.JSON.

When I use the PCL from my projects, at runtime do I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0... or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

I hoped the PCL would somehow contain everything it needed to run.

**How do I design PCL to either require the specific Newtonsoft.JSON or otherwise smartly handle the dependency requirements?**

Added with @Hans Passants Suggestion.
The following is my project.json

```
{
  "supports": {
    "net46.app": {},
    "netcore50.app": {}
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore": "5.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": {
      "imports": "portable-net452"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no clean solution for version mismatches, other than putting it in the GAC.  Pretty unclear what you did to prevent MSBuild from auto-generating the required BindingRedirect element in the app's .config file.  Don't force us to guess please.

Comment: This is my first PCL.  I created a new solution in VS2017, selected type Class Library Portable.  Installed Newtonsoft.Json.  Built Pressing F5 set as release.  Your comment lets me know MSBuild generates a Binding Redirect tho :).  And I do distribute this via Nuget in case that process has an implication.  I will try referencing the DLL directly and verify its not related..